# Java keytool does not find entries in PKCS12 storage on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, keytool, pkcs#12, xades4j

I have the [PKCS12 storage](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/raw/36d21b07476fbe6f9ef6c0719f8996ef5b44bf05/src/test/cert/csrc.nist/test4.p12) (password is `password`, don't worry for security, it is public test certificates) . The storage is not empty according to `openssl`:

```
nk@KubNk:~$ openssl pkcs12  -info  -in /home/nk/tmp/test4.p12  -passin pass:password                                              
MAC:sha1 Iteration 1
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 96 73 26 E7 45 62 15 82 C5 6B 73 96 26 76 47 1B AF 43 5E C2 
    friendlyName: My Certificate
subject=/C=US/O=U.S. Government/OU=DoD/OU=Testing/CN=User1-CP.02.01
issuer=/C=US/O=U.S. Government/OU=Dod/OU=Testing/CN=CA2-CP.02.01
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes: <Empty Attributes>
subject=/C=US/O=U.S. Government/OU=DoD/OU=Testing/CN=Trust Anchor
issuer=/C=US/O=U.S. Government/OU=DoD/OU=Testing/CN=Trust Anchor
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes: <Empty Attributes>
subject=/C=US/O=U.S. Government/OU=Dod/OU=Testing/CN=CA1-CP.02.01
issuer=/C=US/O=U.S. Government/OU=DoD/OU=Testing/CN=Trust Anchor
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes: <Empty Attributes>
subject=/C=US/O=U.S. Government/OU=Dod/OU=Testing/CN=CA2-CP.02.01
issuer=/C=US/O=U.S. Government/OU=Dod/OU=Testing/CN=CA1-CP.02.01
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Warning unsupported bag type: crlBag
Warning unsupported bag type: crlBag
Warning unsupported bag type: crlBag
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2048
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 96 73 26 E7 45 62 15 82 C5 6B 73 96 26 76 47 1B AF 43 5E C2 
    friendlyName: My Certificate
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But `keytool` says that the storage is empty (IBM implementation and Sun/Oracle implementation):

```
nk@KubNk:~$ /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-7-amd64/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore /home/nk/tmp/test4.p12  -storetype pkcs12 -storepass password

Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 0 entries

nk@KubNk:~$ /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-8-amd64/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore /home/nk/tmp/test4.p12  -storetype pkcs12 -storepass password
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 0 entries

nk@KubNk:~$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore /home/nk/tmp/test4.p12  -storetype pkcs12 -storepass password
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 0 entries

nk@KubNk:~$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore /home/nk/tmp/test4.p12  -storetype pkcs12 -storepass password
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 0 entries

nk@KubNk:~$ /opt/ibm/java-x86_64-80/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore /home/nk/tmp/test4.p12  -storetype pkcs12 -storepass password

Тип хранилища ключей: pkcs12
Провайдер хранилища ключей: IBMJCE

Число записей в хранилище ключей: 0
```

Why `keytool` doesn't find entries in storage?

System info:

```
nk@KubNk:~$ uname -a
Linux KubNk 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

Details on the problem below.

We working on `xades4j` library. Recently, about the end of September, I upgrated Kubuntu, and after that library stopped building  on my local computer. I don't sure that it related to system upgrate, but it worked earlier. Moreover, the [Travis CI build](https://travis-ci.org/luisgoncalves/xades4j/builds/435828474) works normal (on Ubuntu 14.04) and author doesn't has problem with build (see [Issue-172](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/issues/172)).

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @dev4life no(( I [converted](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/commit/26e7b5fef7cdd52d9987528a23cd017bbbdc1277) `pkcs12` to `jks`.